# GeoServer Auth by SessionId

Tags: geoserver, wms, url

I'm working on developing a new extension for GeoServer. I want to add ID value to WMS request URL and if ID = 1, the layer should be displayed. If ID = not 1, layer should return empty page. Example;

Normal WMS URL = `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/demo/wms&service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=demo%3Amap&bbox=25.668509999999998%2C35.817496999999996%2C44.834987%2C42.107600999999995&width=768&height=330&srs=EPSG%3A404000&styles=&format=application/openlayers"`

URL I want =
`"http://localhost:8080/geoserver/demo/wms?sessionId=1&service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=demo%3Amap&bbox=25.668509999999998%2C35.817496999999996%2C44.834987%2C42.107600999999995&width=768&height=330&srs=EPSG%3A404000&styles=&format=application/openlayers"`
I added **sessionId=1** and layer should be displayed now.

I created this class;

```
package org.geoserver.helloweb;

import org.geoserver.wms.GetMapCallback;
import org.geoserver.wms.GetMapCallbackAdapter;
import org.geoserver.wms.GetMapRequest;

public class ClusterGetMapCallbackAdapter extends GetMapCallbackAdapter implements GetMapCallback {

    public ClusterGetMapCallbackAdapter() {}

    @Override
    public GetMapRequest initRequest(GetMapRequest request) {
        // Get sessionId parameter
        String sessionId = request.getRawKvp().get("sessionId");

        // if sessionId is not 1 do not open map
        if (sessionId == null || !sessionId.equals("1")) {
            System.out.println("Invalid sessionId, map will not open");
            
            
        }
        return request;
    }
```

But i don't know how to cancel request or return badrequest. How can i do that on geoserver?

Comment: what have you tried so far? what is not working? Also you do realise that the user can easily edit the URLs being sent so there is no security in this

Comment: You should show what you have tried so far so users can guide you better.

Comment: I edited the post. Can you check again? @IanTurton

Comment: Have a look at some of the other security code to see what it does